# Combination of Tests' Power

Tags: multivariate-analysis, statistical-power

I have set of tests. It is not difficult to calculate power for each of them (I have normal distributions and know effect sizes). I would like to infer power of combination of tests.

I.e., $H_0 = $ sample is ill, $H_A = $ sample is healthy. $X_1$ means temperature, $X_2$ denotes running nose, test on $X_1$ has power of $a\%$ and test on $X_2$ has power of $b\%$, and tests have  assumptions of normality on data distributions.

How can I calculate the power of combination of two tests? (I use standard [way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method) for combined p-value calculation)